# How to send the form data up a state using react-hook-form in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am new to React. What I want to do is have a submit button to log the data/state onto the console from the form's input fields which is in another component. To implement this, I have the ResultList component which renders the Filter component which has the form. When the submit button is clicked the data from the input fields should log onto the console. I used react-form-hook to implement the form.
This is the [link to the sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dhanapal-react-ex-1-uerbug)

ResultList component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Filter from './Filter';

import { Button, Dropdown, Input, } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class ResultList extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          myName: '',
          myEmail: ''
      };
    }

    handleParentData = (formModel) => {
      console.log(formModel);

      this.setState({...formModel},()=>alert(JSON.stringify(this.state)));
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>

          <Filter handleData={this.handleParentData}/>
          <p>{this.state.myName}</p>  
          <p>{this.state.email}</p>     
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and Filter component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

export default function Filter() {

  const {register,handleSubmit} = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    // console.log(data);
    this.props.handleData(data);
  } 

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        Name: <input type="text" name="myName" ref={register}/>
        <br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="myEmail" ref={register}/>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to accept props in the functional component, and change the `onSubmit` handler to use `props` and ***not*** `this.props`. Functional components are instanceless and have no `this` object.

```
export default function Filter(props) {

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = data => {
    props.handleData(data);
  } ;

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        Name: <input type="text" name="myName" ref={register}/>
        <br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="myEmail" ref={register}/>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternatively you can destructure props right in the function signature

```
export default function Filter({ handleData }) {

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = data => handleData(data);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        Name: <input type="text" name="myName" ref={register}/>
        <br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="myEmail" ref={register}/>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass **props** to Filter:

```
export default function Filter(props) {
```

and remove `.this.props`:

```
props.handleData(data);
```

Full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

export default function Filter(props) {

  const {register,handleSubmit} = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    // console.log(data);
    props.handleData(data);
  } 

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        Name: <input type="text" name="myName" ref={register}/>
        <br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="myEmail" ref={register}/>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  )

}
```

You also need to change from `{this.state.email}` to `{this.state.myEmail}`

Full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Filter from './Filter';

import { Button, Dropdown, Input, } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class ResultList extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          myName: '',
          myEmail: ''
      };
    }

    handleParentData = (formModel) => {
      console.log(formModel);

      this.setState({...formModel},()=>alert(JSON.stringify(this.state)));
    }


  render() {
    return (
        <div>

          <Filter handleData={this.handleParentData}/>
          <p>{this.state.myName}</p>  
          <p>{this.state.myEmail}</p>     

        </div>
    )
  }
}
```